# Elasticsearch match with filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I need a query that makes partial match on a string and filter outside documents that have a specific value for a field.

I tried this payload for es:

```
    payload = {
    search_request: {
      _source: [ 'name', 'source','pg_id' ],
      query: {
        match: { name: query_string }
        bool: {
          must_not: {
            term: { "source.source": source_value }
          }
        }
      },
      size: 100
    },
    query_hint: query,
    algorithm: algorithm,
    field_mapping: { title: ["_source.name", "_source.source"]}
  }
```

But ES trows this error:

```
    {  
:error=>   {  
:root_cause=>      [  
         {  
:type=>"parse_exception",
:reason=> 
           "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got            [  
               START_OBJECT
            ]            "}], 
       :type=>"            search_phase_execution_exception",
:reason=>"all shards failed",
:phase=>"query",
:grouped=>true,
:failed_shards=>            [  
               {  
:shard=>0,
:index=>"articles",
:node=>"3BUP3eN_TB2-zExigd_k2g",
:reason=>                  {  
:type=>"parse_exception",
:reason=> 
             "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got                     [  
                        START_OBJECT
                     ]                     "
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
:status=>400
      }
```

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4

Answer (score 0):

First of all your json format is not valid. Check for a commas and quotes.
Also if you need just to filtrate documents - filters are much faster than queries. Check [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-filter-context.html)